# RASPBERRY pi3 problema al cargar SO

Tags: asp.net-web-api, raspberry-pi

Tengo un problema con mi raspberry. Creo que la apague mal y ahora tengo un problema de configuración. No muestra nada por la pantalla LCD. Y por hdmi muestra la carga del Sistema Operativo hasta que aparece error. Ya he formateado la sd y he montado de nuevo el Sistema Operativo pero aun no funciona. Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: ya hiciste prueba con otra SD? puedes probar con una memoria USB y otro sistema operativo

Comment: puedes indicar que error te sale cuando proyectas por HDMI?

Comment: Tal y como está redactada la pregunta, esta publicación no parece ser sobre programación.

Comment: 1 Cual es el error que te sale en la pantalla HDMI?
2. Si ya cargaste el SO cual error te salio?

Comment: Tengo un artículo completo de cómo instalar el sistema en el Pi, pero básicamente tiene que descargar la imagen en: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest A continuación, utiliza esta otra herramienta para grabar la imagen de Linux en el SD (enchufado a su computadora) https://etcher.io/ Artículo (pt-BR) https://medium.com/@thiagoloureiro/raspberry-pi-net-core-2-0-parte-1-setup-68252f36ed28